# How to remove remove to take only numerical values from string using regex java?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
   String textString = "Power for CH2 234 45";
```

I need a regex to remove white spaces between numbers but also want to avoid if there is a non-numeric value before a number like

```
String texString="23445";
```

Here want to avoid the numerical value after any non-numeric value  Here in my String want to avoid the numeric value also after H there are 2 but I just want to make a string like "23445".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex, `(?<!\w)\d+(?!\w)`.

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "Power for CH2 234 45",
                    "Power for 2CH C2H CH2 234 45"
                ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + getNumber(s)));
    
    }
    static String getNumber(String textString) {
        return Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)\\d+(?!\\w)")
                .matcher(textString)
                .results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Power for CH2 234 45 => 23445
Power for 2CH C2H CH2 234 45 => 23445
```

**Non-`Stream` version:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrings = { "Power for CH2 234 45", "Power for 2CH C2H CH2 234 45" };

        for (String s : testStrings) {
            System.out.println(getNumber(s));
        }
    }

    static String getNumber(String textString) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)\\d+(?!\\w)").matcher(textString);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            sb.append(matcher.group());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ThKTei/1):**

[image]

Comment: `223445` is incorrect result, question is asking for result to be `23445`. Read the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: Fails if input is e.g. `"Power for 2CH C2H CH2 234 45"`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  I am using a lower java Version so the above methods is not working in my code

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is much easier to use regex to find what you want to keep, instead of finding what you want to remove. In this case you want to keep "words" that consists purely of digits.

With Java 9+, that's very easy, using regex `\b\d+\b`:

```java
String textString = "Power for CH2 234 45";

String numString = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b").matcher(textString)
        .results().map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(numString); // 23445
```

Comment: I am using a lower java Version so the above methods is not working in my code

Comment: @NitinThakor which version are you using